# Does ASP.net 1.1 support Generic HttpHandlers?

Tags: .net, asp.net, httphandler, ihttphandler

I need to get an image from a SQL Server as a byte[], and load it to a WebControl.Image. The only seemingly good way to do it that I found is to implement IHttpHandler and handle the request accordingly.

But I'm stuck to using asp.net 1.1. Does it support ashx files?

Comment: You don't need ashx files to implement an IHttpHandler. Handlers can be registered in web.config too.

Comment: Really? Ok, I didn't know that - I'll look it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) interface is supported in .NET 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0.